# JS static method of a Class can't call other method: TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, static-methods, es6-class

I have a class with two methods:

```
class Solution {
  swap(arr, idx1, idx2) {
    let temp = arr[idx1];
    arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
    arr[idx2] = temp;
  }

  static bubbleSort(arr) {
    for (let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) this.swap(arr, i, j);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

When I call `Solution.bubbleSort([2,1,3])` I get `TypeError: this.swap is not a function`.

It works when I make swap() a static method, but it wasn't my intention:

```
static swap(arr, idx1, idx2) { ... }
```

I've tried to use constructor to bind `this` to bubbleSort() method but it didn't help so I guess it's not a problem with a scope?

```
constructor() {
  this.bubbleSort = this.bubbleSort.bind(this);
}
```

I tried also to use the arrow functions but it didn't help either.

My ideal solution would be `swap()` as a private helper method and `bubbleSort()` as a public method (like in Python). But I know that private methods are a proposal, not fully supported.

Why it works when I make `swap()` a static method?
How can I write it better?

PS. don't look on algorithm, I know time complexity is O(n2) :P

Comment: Either make both static or none, those are your options. You cannot have one static and the other not and expect it to work, because the non-static one needs to be invoked with / on an instance of `Solution` which you intentionally don't have since you made the first function static.

Comment: A static method has no `this` object, so how could `this.swap()` work?

Comment: Why does `swap` need to be non-static? It never uses `this`.

Comment: `swap`, being an instance method, can only be called on an instance of `Solution` (or from the prototype). using it the way you are doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Whether a method is private or public is a separate concern from whether it's static or not. Making it non-static in an attempt to make it private doesn't make sense, apart from the unsolvable problem that you can't use `this` in a static method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm practicing algorithms for a technical interview and in one course I heard that it's good to wrap our code in class to show that we know it and make it better structured. But this course is in Python. I tried to implement the same approach in JS.

Comment: @ChrisG I didn't know that a static method has no `this` object. And binding `this` in a `constructor` to static method doasn't work? 
I have to read further, thx :)

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance, but there is no current instance in the context of a static method. Binding it makes no sense either because the constructor is called when you create an instance, but calling a static method from a non-static one is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to make `swap()` an instance method. But if you really need it, you can create a temporary instance and use that.

```
class Solution {
  swap(arr, idx1, idx2) {
    let temp = arr[idx1];
    arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
    arr[idx2] = temp;
  }

  static bubbleSort(arr) {
    let temp_instance = new Solution;
    for (let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) temp_instance.swap(arr, i, j);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

But there's not really any reason for `swap()` to be an instance method, since it never accesses any properties of the object it's called on.

Comment: Thanks a lot - there is no reason. I'm practicing algorithms for tech interview and I heard that it's good to wrap a solution in a class to make our code better structured and to show that we know OOP ;)

But the course I follow is in Python and I'm not sure if making a class for this solution makes any sense in JS? Or maybe I just should use static for both methods and that would be ok?

Comment: It's possible to use classes with only static methods as a form of modules.

Comment: @ŁukaszMatuszewski No, you should not use a `class` that consists of only static methods. Use an object literal instead, if you want methods on a namespace for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve this code by leveraging [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

If your function bubblesort() is going to call swap(), you should pass in swap() as a dependency.

```
static bubbleSort(arr, swap) {
    for (let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) swap(arr, i, j);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

Your bubblesort() function is now *simpler* because it does not need to reference anything outside of it's own scope. Your initial question about scope is now moot, which is a good thing.

Comment: thanks, but to pass `swap` as an argument I would have to make an instance of Solution class and then pass it. I wanted to make it simpler and just use `Solution.bubbleSort(arr)` :)

I'm from React and most of a time I use FP so I agree that dependency injection is a better aprouch, but this time I think that I should make swap a static method. Or convert Solution to an function and use Module Pattern :)